# Overnight wifi/shower facilities in Haneda airport?

Tags: airports, wifi, hnd

I'm arriving just before the last train, so assume I'll be sleeping in the airport, or trying to.  From the looks of it online this is possible, but I'm wondering if there's wifi and showers anywhere in the airport? (not necessarily together)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The showers are available on the Arrival Lobby on the Second Floor.

Available 24 hours

Fees
¥1,030/30min.(with drink coupon)
¥520 for each 15min. thereafter
* As of April 1, 2014.

- Towels, shampoo, conditioner, body soap and dryer provided.

http://www.haneda-airport.jp/inter/en/map/floormap/map.html?floorId=MAP002&serviceId=30

WiFi is available in the terminal

Steps for FREE wireless internet access are as follows:

1. Choose the network ID(ESS-ID) "HANEDA-FREE-WIFI" on your PC or internet device. No WEP key is needed.
2. Open your web browser.
3. Procedures for the connection are indicated on the web browser. You must register your name and e-mail address.
4. Enjoy free wireless broadband!

http://www.haneda-airport.jp/inter/en/premises/service/internet.html

Comment: Can confirm they were amazing showers.  Although didn't get a drink coupon :/